# Windows 8 get ItemControl width after databind

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am creating a Windows 8 app with Itemcontrol and binding a list of data to display news. I need to create animation like news ticker in HTML as displayed in link: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/9/
How will i achieve this?

Code:

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="lstdata"  >
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate  >
                    <DataTemplate   >
                        <!--Date-->
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Path=ModifedDate,Converter={StaticResource DatetimeToStringFormatConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1"  FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="13.33" />
                            <TextBlock   Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Path=Title , Mode=TwoWay}" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="13.33" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>


var  newsViewModel = new  NewsViewModel();
          await  newsViewModel.GetNews();
          lstdata.ItemsSource = newsViewModel.NewsList;
```

Animation:

```
FlipViewNews.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();

            DoubleAnimation animateX = new DoubleAnimation();
            animateX.From = 0;
            animateX.To = 200;
            animateX.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400);

            Storyboard.SetTarget(animateX, FlipViewNews.RenderTransform);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animateX, "TranslateTransform.X");

            Storyboard story = new Storyboard();
            story.Children.Add(animateX);
            story.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
            story.Begin();
```

I have been able to make animation work. The above code is working the only problem is that i need to get ItemsControl Actual width after all items get binded. How would i get that so that i can create a animation like marquee in HTML??

Comment: You'll need to use some animation code, either in Xaml, or in C#. Could you please edit the question to include what you've tried? If you'd used WinJs+HTML, it would have been easier to clone. :)

Comment: I have made the changes and added the code. But that is not working. Plus i need to make it dynamic as per the items in itemcontrol. how would i achieve that?

Comment: Are you referring to the scroll to the bottom when first load?

Comment: I need to get the width so that i can animate Itemcontrol using the translate animation like a news ticker so I need to get the width in order to set To and From property

Answer (score 0):

Can you add a `SizeChanged` listener, then get the ActualWidth of the element in response as binding affects the size?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.sizechanged.aspx

Comment: I believe if the itemscontrol is virtualized, the size of the control could also change as you scroll, if further items are larger than previous items?

Comment: I need to get the width so that i can animate Itemcontrol using the translate animation like a news ticker so I need to get the width in order to set To and From property..

Comment: I understand what you need, i'm just saying that the width can change as the itemscontrol content changes, so you may not be able to just get the width one time.  you either need to do data binding to `ActualWidth`, or add a `SizeChanged` listener.

Comment: When i add Size changed event it doesn't give me the width every time i add a new item.

Comment: I didn't say it *will* change, I said the width *can* change. if the items were aaa, aaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa, the `ActualWidth` *could* change every time an item was added.  It also depends on the containing control, what horizontal alignement/etc are set to.

Comment: I do understand that when i add sizechanged event in the above code it doesn't change or get hit when item get binded to itemcontrol. Can you please let me know exactly what u mean by updating the code above.